# Azure - moving from free services to Basic Mobile Services pay-as-you-go

Tags: azure, payment, azure-mobile-services

I have actually pay-as-you-go plan in my account right now and I am using free 20MB database to all my projects in this account. I've created mobile services for my mobile app and it's time to release this project. So I think the best for me right now is move from Free Mobile Services to Basic so I can have unlimited devices to use this. But I don't know how much database size and bandwidth I would need. I just want to set my plan to Basic and create new database and then pay how much bandwidth and database size I would need.

I found [this calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=mobile) and I just want to buy that Basic services with 1 unit and I just don't want to fill any other things (not because I don't want them because I just don't know how many and that it would be great that with rising app using there would be rising too). Is it possible?

I hope I explained my problem well.

Btw: What unit means in "1.5M API calls per unit"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can continue to use Free SQL DB with Basic tier of Windows Azure Mobile Services. SQL and Mobile Services are separate items on your subscription and each can be scaled independently of the other. In practice if you have a lot of load, you will likely need to scale both - for architectural reasons.

Egress bandwidth for Mobile Service responses to the client is included in Mobile Services pricing. If you don't use SQL in the same data center, you may incur separate bandwidth charges. Although for latency reasons, we strongly recommend using a database and Mobile Service in the same data center which also eliminates egress costs for Mobile Service - SQL interaction.

You can purchase 1-6 units of Basic tier of Mobile Services. Each unit provides 1.5M API calls per month. So if you buy 2 Basic units, you will get 3M API calls per month and so on.

Thanks.

Dinesh Kulkarni

(Program Manager, Windows Azure)

Comment: i didn't understand about " /unit" can you please elaborate